# running a executable shell file from a shell file

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm doing a project where the user runs a .sh file which will then run a executable .sh file.

The file is called wifi.sh and then inside this is the file location to fluxion.sh, but when it runs, it does not run the fluxion program. How can I get this to work.

Comment: Could you please show (in the question, not comments) what happens you try to run the `wifi.sh` script?

Comment: How do you know, that fluxion.sh isn't run? How is it invoced (let's see the code!). How do you invoke wifi.sh? Shebang issues, file attributes, PATH issues, permissions, conditions in the outer script, ... - Error message?

Answer (score 0):

It depends slightly in which context you plan to run `fluxion` and what should happen, once that tool terminates.

**Option I: `exec`**

Features: does not return, saves processes

wifi.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATHTOFLUXION=/usr/local/bin/fluxion
exec $PATHTOFLUXION
echo this code is never reached
```

**Option II: just calling**

Features: does return, maximum simplicity

wifi.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATHTOFLUXION=/usr/local/bin/fluxion
$PATHTOFLUXION
echo "I just returned from $PATHTOFLUXION"
```

**Option III: `source`**

Features: If the called tool is in turn a shell script that also sets variables you want to access after the tool exited, these are preserved.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATHTOFLUXION=/usr/local/bin/fluxion
source $PATHTOFLUXION
echo "$PATHTOFLUXION was a shellscript and set $DATAFROMFLUX"
```

Comment: ls -l $PATHTOFLUXION might be more informative.